# 502 Bad Gateway When callback social of facebook by laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook, laravel-socialite

I'm using package socialite of Laravel to login by facebook or gmail. In function callback social, It has been successfully login with google but it failed with facebook.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4qJv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6B0x.png)